# pgfplots legend disappearing with externalization

Tags: pgfplots, legend, externalize

I have an issue with a combination of a special legend I am doing in a pgfplot, and with using tikz externalization. See the MWE below. The legend will not appear if I use externalization, but if I remove the externalization, the legend appears.

Any ideas on how to get the legend, while still using externalization?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=ext/]
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{width=\textwidth,height=6cm}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \vspace{30pt}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                legend style={
                    anchor = south,
                    column sep = 0pt,
                    legend columns = 2,
                    at = {(0.9\textwidth,1.1)},
                    overlay,
                    font=\scriptsize
                }
                ]
                \addplot {x^3 - x^2};
                \addplot {x^3 +2};
                \addplot {x^2};
                \addplot {4*x+2};

                \legend{plot a, plot b, plot c, plot d};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{cap 1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}    
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                \addplot {x^3 + x^2};
                \addplot {-2*x^3 -1};
                \addplot {x^2};
                \addplot {4*x+2};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{cap 2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{...}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The external PDF contains the drawing instructions for your legend, but since it is excluded from the bounding box, it is clipped away. I believe this is a limitation of PDF (or the way PDF's bounding box is generated in TeX). I think it used to work for `dvips`, but I might be wrong.

A portable way (i.e. one which works for `pdftex` as well) is to use `legend to name` and omit the `overlay` option. This key allows you to "detach" the legend from its parent axis, and place it somewhere where you like it using `\ref{<the name>}`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=ext/]
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{width=\textwidth,height=6cm}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \ref{mylegend}

    \vspace{30pt}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                legend style={
                    anchor = south,
                    column sep = 0pt,
                    legend columns = 2,
                    at = {(0.9\textwidth,1.1)},
                    font=\scriptsize
                },
                legend to name=mylegend,
                ]
                \addplot {x^3 - x^2};
                \addplot {x^3 +2};
                \addplot {x^2};
                \addplot {4*x+2};

                \legend{plot a, plot b, plot c, plot d};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{cap 1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}    
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                \addplot {x^3 + x^2};
                \addplot {-2*x^3 -1};
                \addplot {x^2};
                \addplot {4*x+2};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{cap 2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{...}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\ref{mylegend}` needs to be placed just as any other `\includegraphics`. In this case, I inserted it in the centered header of the figures. You may want to adopt it to your needs (and the spacing above/below of it).

This label/referencing stuff has builtin support in the `external` library -- to some extend. The "to some extend" means that you have to externalize the `\ref` *manually*; the output `.log` file states which command is to be entered in the command line. The (linux) `mode=list and make` does not have this limitation; it can generate the required graphics automatically. These limitations around externalization of labels/references will be lifted with the next release of PGF (or pgfplots, whichever comes first).